# How to remove UIBarButtonItem tintColor animation on iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, uibarbuttonitem

I have a BarButtonItem animation here:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:AnimDurationTintColorHint delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    [view performSelector:@selector(setTintColor:) withObject:UIColor.blackColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  ........
}];
```

because UIBarButtonItem has no layer property, I can't use .layer removeAllAnimations to stop the endless animation assigned.

How to remove that?

Answer (score 3):

You have to take leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItem and then set enabled property of UIBarButtonItem to NO.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"];
    UIButton *btnMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnMenu.frame = CGRectMake( 10, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnMenu setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnMenu];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: I figured that out. use     [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions animations:^{
        [view performSelector:@selector(setTintColor:) withObject:UIColor.whiteColor];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];